# StackOverflowError on KitKat because of vector drawables

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, runtime-error, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have a custom view with the following view hierarchy:

```
[LinearLayout]
  [CardView]
    [LinearLayout]
      [RecyclerView]
```

Each item of this last `RecyclerView` contains **3 vector drawables**. When i run the app on KitKat (api 19), a `StackOverflowError` happens

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.tsse.spain.myvodafone, PID: 3405
     java.lang.StackOverflowError
         at android.graphics.Matrix.mapVectors(Matrix.java:684)
         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VPathRenderer.getMatrixScale(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1300)
         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VPathRenderer.drawPath(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1207)
         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VPathRenderer.drawGroupTree(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1184)
         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VPathRenderer.draw(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1193)
         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VectorDrawableCompatState.updateCachedBitmap(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1023)
         at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.draw(VectorDrawableCompat.java:366)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14450)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:4477)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3869)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
         at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:472)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13357)
         at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
         at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14182)
         at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:4477)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940
```

I'm enabling vector drawables with `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in the `Application` class's `onCreate()` and `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in `build.gradle`

When i use normal **PNG** drawables the error doesn't happen.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Compat vectors are suitable mostly for simple icons (with 1-4 paths each), if your vectors are too complex it won't work.

Comment: i had the same issue but i solved this problem using the following method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by converting the vector drawable to a `Bitmap` first, then give it to the ImageView using `ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap)`. This is less performant, but gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

In `onBindViewHolder` create your **vector-drawable** programatically and set it to your views like this :-

```
   Drawable your_vector_drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), R.drawable.vectorDrawable, null);
```

Now set this drawable to your view in `onBindViewHolder`...

```
  yourView.setBackground(your_vector_drawable);
```

This will hopefully solve :)

> This is a lower api issue...

Comment: still the same error happens, with same starcktrace

Comment: did remove all drawable int  from xml ??

Comment: yes, was using `app:srcCompat` and removed all of them

Comment: check my answer